# Exception:Input array Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, combobox, static-methods

To explain what I'm doing I'm try to load the data in a particular column to a combo box for this I using a static method.Exception jumps out on the **7 line of the below code**.Whenever I run the program this line throws the exception, **Input array Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.**

```
void DataGridViewModules()
{
    DataRow dr;
    CommonDBTransaction c = new CommonDBTransaction();
    string sql = "SELECT MId FROM Module";
    DataTable dt = c.searchData(sql);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select Module--" }; //Exception jumps out here
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
    metroComboBoxMod.ValueMember = "MId";
    metroComboBoxMod.DisplayMember = "MId";
    metroComboBoxMod.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Static Method utilized to query data is,

```
public DataTable searchData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....constring here...))//connection string was added
        {
            using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
               da.Fill(table);
        }
        return table;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? how can I fix it & reference would suffice ?

Comment: Is this a real copy/paste of the exception?

Comment: @Rafalon Yes it is

Comment: @Alexey and people accepting his/her edit, be careful as code formatting actually changed the number of lines and therefore the position of **line 9**

Comment: @Rafalon got it, my fault

Comment: @MRDR instead of providing a line number, why don't you add a comment **in** the code saying something like `// <-- exception thrown here` so there won't be any confusion?

Comment: Thanks @Rafalon will update it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're only retrieving one column in your select query but you're adding a 2 column array to you're new row.

You may be able to get away with the below:

```
DataRow dr;
CommonDBTransaction c = new CommonDBTransaction();
string sql = "SELECT MId FROM Module";
DataTable dt = c.searchData(sql);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "--Select Module--";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
metroComboBoxMod.ValueMember = "MId";
metroComboBoxMod.DisplayMember = "MId";
metroComboBoxMod.DataSource = dt;
```

Otherwise, you will likely need a separate column for both the ValueMember and the DisplayMember:

```
DataRow dr;
CommonDBTransaction c = new CommonDBTransaction();
string sql = "SELECT MId AS MId, MId AS DisplayId FROM Module";
DataTable dt = c.searchData(sql);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = 0;
dr[1] = "--Select Module--";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
metroComboBoxMod.ValueMember = "MId";
metroComboBoxMod.DisplayMember = "DisplayId";
metroComboBoxMod.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Removed  dr.ItemArray = new object[] {"--Select Module--" }; //Exception jumps out here works like a charm thanks @qwertydog !

Comment: No problem, see edit if it's not displaying correctly

Comment: Works like a charm just tested it. Thanks once again !